# Sorting rows of a faceted chart in vega lite

Tags: vega-lite

Is there some magic to sort sub-charts from a `row` encoding by the number of items per row?

[In this example with the cars dataset](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gUVgCcx2XAWJkhtBszacepZJubcjpbbtLx0R2PMUVAF91CEgMIwBrM1AIMLwAT0JkM0h2XzUNeO5uMTxGQjM8I1ZkDRCNSAB3Rk0WM2kABkbQqHRWPG5YRgAvFP0oROTUgDNmNSh4ZV1GJVhUwnRNFyVqSDAKsOQlKZW1-SyoI24qmMOwseQxTVSAeSNGJhVVQaT+qCVuVFn0UxfIWCLeCzfZgFrnXDIJbIIzYWJxBGQMTodhXACCqzE73BCMRyNRYgAMoxvngzABGACsONxYXx6Ik1BUOCRyBGZNatKRKKuADFpgBlXrvckAJk5uO5BP5SjJLIAmuhZUZ0BglOgKJlafFmFizEpWGIxBDNpLFEY5W0ENs9pBDqawgAPM5c9DUahGYR4d6QKasWUTSBDH0AR1YSvyunyVC1kvQjsY830kA9tSKJWQ-zcjG2lqD3EKQXtEsgCRdksu11SAGEEhIlJoYfN-sHUp9vuq-hDIPHE-rDcaEUWIKbfcoxqD4WEKDnTsnYMVuJEfYz8B7kGWHW0E0mwMBIJovuhZgB1Wr1HCNYcbEBFoA), i would want to have USA at the top, because it contains the most items, then Japan, then Europe:

[image]

Maybe with the `items` property of the row header data store?

Answer (score 1):

I used aggregate transform to calculate the number of items per Origin and Cylinder and a subsequent [join aggregate transformation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/joinaggregate.html) to sum up the number of items per Origin:

```
  "transform": [{
      "aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "Count"}],
      "groupby": ["Cylinders", "Origin"]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "Count", "as": "OriginCount"}],
      "groupby": ["Origin"]
    }
  ]
```

I can then display `Count` on the x-axis as any other data variable and sort the `row` encoding by the calculated `OriginCount`:

```
  "encoding": {
    "row": {
      "field": "Origin", "type": "nominal",
      "sort": { "field": "OriginCount", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Count", "type": "quantitative"
    },
    ...
]
```

Giving me the following grouped bar chart:
[image: Sorted groped bar char]

See in the [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-SQPCgA)
The full spec for reference:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": { "url": "https://vega.github.io/editor/data/cars.json"},
  "transform": [{
      "aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "Count"}],
      "groupby": ["Cylinders", "Origin"]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "Count", "as": "OriginCount"}],
      "groupby": ["Origin"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "tooltip": true
  },
  "width": 400,
  "encoding": {
    "row": {
      "field": "Origin", "type": "nominal",
      "sort": { "field": "OriginCount", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Count", "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Cylinders", "type": "nominal"
    }
  }
}
```